# count and index characters in a column

Tags: bash, indexing, awk, grep

I have a file `system.xyz` with several columns:

```
          43
  Built with Packmol
  O           37.536208       36.873149        9.514500
  C           37.768292       35.784076       10.014380
  N           37.749829       34.667899        9.235406
  C           38.014779       33.336113        9.750827
  C           37.921777       32.283049        8.635104
  C           38.203826       30.885654        9.187454
```

and need to change them to:

```
@atom:o1 @mol: $atom:O 0 37.536208 36.873149 9.514500
@atom:c1 @mol: $atom:C 0 37.768292 35.784076 10.014380
@atom:n1 @mol: $atom:N 0 37.749829 34.667899 9.235406
@atom:c2 @mol: $atom:C 0 38.014779 33.336113 9.750827
@atom:c3 @mol: $atom:C 0 37.921777 32.283049 8.635104
@atom:c4 @mol: $atom:C 0 38.203826 30.885654 9.187454
```

I have managed to use this
`grep -A43 Built system.xyz | awk '{print "@atom:"tolower($1), "@mol: $atom:"$1,"0",$2,$3,$4}'`

```
@atom:built @mol: $atom:Built 0 with Packmol 
@atom:o @mol: $atom:O 0 37.536208 36.873149 9.514500
@atom:c @mol: $atom:C 0 37.768292 35.784076 10.014380
@atom:n @mol: $atom:N 0 37.749829 34.667899 9.235406
@atom:c @mol: $atom:C 0 38.014779 33.336113 9.750827
@atom:c @mol: $atom:C 0 37.921777 32.283049 8.635104
@atom:c @mol: $atom:C 0 38.203826 30.885654 9.187454
```

but I have to manually enter the indexes of each character of the first column. Is there a way to count and index the characters in the first column?

Comment: If you thought `grep -A43 Built` meant "match Built after 43" that's incorrect, it means "match Built and include the 43 lines that follow". If that's not the case it'd be nice if you explained why you need the `-A43`, I see no reference to 43 lines in your question

Comment: Hi yes, the 43 at the beginning of the file actually tells me the number of lines after `Built` so it'd be nice to also automatically read 43 instead of manually writing `-A43`

Comment: Are there other lines after the 43 ones that you shouldn't process? If so, is there any kind of delimiter, or do the lines that follow differ in any way, e.g. a new number & "Built with Packmol" line? because you might not need to read this number if there are other ways to find the end of what you're supposed to read. That said extracting the number wouldn't be hard either, for instance you could use `grep -B1 Built | grep -Eo '[0-9]+'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```sh
awk '
    BEGIN {fmt = "@atom:%s%d @mol: $atom:%s 0"}
    {$1 = sprintf(fmt, tolower($1), ++count[tolower($1)], $1)}
    1
'
```

Comment: Never thought of doing ~ `fmt="%s"; printf fmt, var`. TIL, thanks.

Comment: That is brilliant ! Thanks for this! EDIT: To those working on converting xyz files to moltemplate lt files, I got the symbols wrong. This works like a charm:
`cat system.xyz | awk '
    BEGIN {fmt = "$atom:%s%d $mol: @atom:%s 0"}
    {$1 = sprintf(fmt, tolower($1), ++count[tolower($1)], $1)}
    1
'`

Comment: @Hud No need for that `cat | awk`, awk can handle files by itself. Use `awk ... file` instead.

Comment: Cheers. Final edit  `awk '     BEGIN {fmt = "$atom:%s%d $mol:.. @atom:%s 0"}     {$1 = sprintf(fmt, tolower($1), ++count[tolower($1)], $1)}     1 ' system.xyz`